# ASP.net - Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named 

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I'm building a website in ASP.net and using a MySQL connector 5.1 to connect to an online MySQL database. I have a dataset with all my tables, but when I try to configure or add a new table I get the follow error:

```
Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named "System.data.odbc"
```

Anyone know anything about this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the .NET Connector or the ODBC driver? They are different.

Comment: I'm using this http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the ODBC driver. IMHO you'd be better off with the .NET Connector:

[Connector/Net is a fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: and can't use it, my hostingsite doesn't support that.

Comment: ODBC is an older generic technology, whereas the .NET connector is a fully managed ADO.NET provider, and will deliver better performance when developing .NET applications. At the end of the day it kind of comes down to personal choice as well a bit, as both will likely do what you want.